# How do I make Python 3.4 use an randrange variable only once?

Tags: python, random

I am currently building a little quiz game using Python 3.4's randrange function. I have it setup and working to automatically select a variable to use to select a question. My only question is how can I make it use the question only once per time that you take the test.

```
#Main Game
def game():
    score = 0
    while True:
        irand = randrange(0,4)
        #Question 1
        if irand == 1:
            quiz += 1
            print ("What was the first Pokémon?")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[A] Bulbasaur")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[B] Pikachu")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[C] Nicki Minaj")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[D] Arceus")
            time.sleep(1)
            question1 = input ("Your Answer: ")
            if question1 == 'a':
                score += 1
                print ("Your answer is correct!")
                time.sleep(2)
                print ("Your score is now %s" % score + "!")
                time.sleep(4)
                cls()
                continue
            if question1 == 'b' or 'c' or 'd':
                print ("Your answer is incorrect!")
                time.sleep(4)
                cls()
                continue
        #Question 2
        if irand == 2:
            quiz += 1
            print ("What item shares experience with your party of Pokémon?")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[A] Exp Distributor")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[B] Exp Party")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[C] Exp Share")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[D] Exp Gain")
            time.sleep(1)
            question2 = input ("Your Answer: ")
            if question2 == 'c':
                score += 1
                print ("Your answer is correct!")
                time.sleep(2)
                print ("Your score is now %s" % score + "!")
                time.sleep(4)
                cls()
                continue
            if question2 == 'a' or 'b' or 'd':
                print ("Your answer is incorrect!")
                time.sleep(4)
                cls()
                continue
        #Question 3
        if irand == 3:
            quiz += 1
            print ("What Pokémon is the god Pokémon?")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[A] Arceus")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[B] Magikarp")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[C] Meowth")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("[D] Pikachu")
            time.sleep(1)
            question3 = input ("Your Answer: ")
            if question3 == 'a':
                score += 1
                print ("Your answer is correct!")
                time.sleep(2)
                print ("Your score is now %s" % score + "!")
                time.sleep(4)
                cls()
                continue 
            if question3 == 'b' or 'c' or 'd':
                print ("Your answer is incorrect!")
                time.sleep(4)
                cls()
                continue
        #Quiz Ending
        if quiz == 20:
            print ("The quiz is now over.")
            time.sleep(2)
```

I haven't tried anything yet because I am still learning Python. Any help would be very appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similiar as you'd do on the real life: you have a set of cards in your hands, shuffle them randomly, take the first, discard it, take another from the deck, etc.

In Python you can do that by using a list of questions, randomly shuffling the questions and then taking each question one at a time.

Example:

```
>>> import random
>>> cards = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> random.shuffle(cards)
>>> cards
[3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of choosing a random number each time, try shuffling a list of numbers to randomize the question order:

```
from random import shuffle

# range creates a list: [1, 2, 3]
questions = range(1, 4)
shuffle(questions)

for q in questions:
    if q == 1:
        #question 1
    if q == 2:
        #question 2
```

To keep improving your program, think about maybe using a dictionary to store your questions, and writing a function to handle the question and answer part. That way, you only write the question code once, and it can be used over and over again with new questions.